# Split doesn't show all strings

Tags: c#, string, split

I was making a application (Windows forms) that would run a command and check for arguments. I tried using split for the arguments, but I noticed only one string was showing, which was the command instead of the argument. What am I doing wrong?

Input:

```
sicr -dev
```

RunCommands.cs:

```
    class RunCommands
    {
        public string Parse(string command)
        {
            string[] args = command.Split(' ');
            if (command.StartsWith("sicr"))
            {
                return SICR(args);
            }
            return "Unknown console error.";
        }

        private string SICR(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (string arg in args)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(arg);
                if (arg == "-dev")
                {
                    return "SUCCES";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "ERROR: Not enough administrator levels.";
                }
            }
            return "ERROR: Unknown.";
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
sicr (Supposed to be -dev)
```

Comment: You're returning the first argument, which is why it's not getting to `-dev`.

Comment: Ohhhhh i see! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you're returning the first argument, which is why it's not getting to the `-dev` command. You can change the function to be:

```
private string SICR(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length == 0)
    {
        return "ERROR: Unknown.";
    }

    return args.Contains("-dev") ? "SUCCESS" : "ERROR: Not enough administrator levels.";
}
```

Which will search `args` for `-dev` for you.